# Como usar sistema de posts do Jekyll para fazer app

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache-cordova

Eu estou a fazer uma app android, usando apache cordova. Eu quero saber como fazer um sistema de "posts" como no Jekyll, ele simplesmente pega em arquivos de texto e transforma-os em post. Por cada ficheiro .txt ele cria um post. Como posso fazer isso?

Por exemplo, no arquivo .txt eu tenho:

```
### Titulo
## Texto
# link do botão
```

E ele gera um post tipo este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Montei o CSS que está abaixo. Acho que faz o que você quer. Não sei se está exatamente conforme o original porque você não postou a imagem em sua resolução original, mas seja como for, está bem próximo.

O HTML a ser preenchido é o que é representado pela `<div>` de classe `caixa`. Essa `<div>` é criada pelo jQuery na função `fazCaixa` usando-se um pedaço de TXT assim:

> Torre de Belem###A Torre de Belém localiza-se na freguesia de Belém, concelho e distrito de Lisboa, em Portugal. Na margem direita do rio Tejo, onde existiu outrora a praia de Belém, era primitivamente cercada pelas águas em todo o seu perímetro.###Google Maps

Esse formato corresponde ao título seguido do conteúdo e depois o texto do botão, separados por `###`. Não deve ser muito difícil fazer-se adaptações no formato do texto se for necessário caso algum outro formato seja desejável.

Clique no botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> lá em baixo para ver o resultado.

```js
function fazCaixa(txt) {
    var parts = post.split("###");
    var titulo = parts[0];
    var texto = parts[1];
    var botao = parts[2];
    var esqueleto = $(""
            + "<div class='caixa'>"
            + "    <h2></h2>"
            + "    <p></p>"
            + "    <div class='bt'>"
            + "        <button></button>"
            + "    </div>"
            + "</div>"
    );
    var div = $(esqueleto);
    div.find("h2").html(titulo);
    div.find("p").html(texto);
    div.find("button").html(botao);
    $(".area-externa").append(div);
}

var post = "Torre de Belem###A Torre de Belém localiza-se na freguesia de Belém, concelho e distrito de Lisboa, em Portugal. Na margem direita do rio Tejo, onde existiu outrora a praia de Belém, era primitivamente cercada pelas águas em todo o seu perímetro.###Google Maps";

fazCaixa(post);
```

```css
.area-externa {
    width: 330px;
}

.caixa {
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgb(160, 160, 160), -3px 0 rgb(0, 123, 255);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.caixa p, .caixa h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.caixa p {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.caixa .bt {
    text-align: right;
}

.caixa .bt button {
    background-color: rgb(0, 123, 255);
    color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="area-externa">
</div>
```